# What sets limits on maximum Collection size/count in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I am using a nested Collection to store validation data from Excel, of the form: coll1(case)(subtype)(item).

My code is essentially looping through a flat input list and bin sorting the contents into collections - the top level collection is a collection of validation data for all data sources (cases), the second tier is a type collection (within each case, there are different possible types/classes of data) and the final tier is the valid list of tags/labels for things of that particular class/type.

In the code below, **inp** is read in from a vertical stack of Excel cells, but is essentially a list of (unique) Strings of the form "\validation_data_class\case\type\label" - hence the Split() into the labels() array to then parse.

```
Public tag_data As Collection

Private Sub load_tags(inp As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, label() As String
    Dim case_name As String, type_name As String, tag_name As String
    Dim tmp_coll As Collection, tmp_coll2 As Collection
    
    Set tag_data = New Collection
    
    For i = LBound(inp) To UBound(inp) ' Check this works if only one entry in the list - may need IsArray() check
        label = Split(inp(i, 1), "\")
        Select Case label(1)
        Case "tag"
            ' Extract the case name from the label and get its number, so we can store data in the right element of tag_data()
            case_name = label(2): If Not KeyExists(tag_data, case_name) Then Set tmp_coll = New Collection: tag_data.Add tmp_coll, case_name
            
            ' Extract the type name from the label and store it, if needed
            type_name = label(3): Set tmp_coll = tag_data(case_name)
            If Not KeyExists(tmp_coll, type_name) Then Set tmp_coll2 = New Collection: tmp_coll.Add tmp_coll2, type_name
            
            ' Extract the actual tag and store it in the list (assumes we have ensured no duplicates already)
            tag_name = label(4): Set tmp_coll = tag_data(case_name)(type_name)
            Debug.Assert i < 719
            tmp_coll.Add tag_name, tag_name

        Case "prop"
            ' Still to implement
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub

Function KeyExists(coll As Collection, key As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    IsObject (coll.Item(key))
    
    KeyExists = True
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' Do nothing
End Function
```

The problem I am having is that it gets as far as my Debug.Assert line and then silently fails on that 719th addition to the lowest-level Collection. Weirdly it will run if I don't use keys for the lowest-level Collection, which then allows me to add the final 2 items (in this particular case, I need 721 items in that Collection, but it could be more or less in other scenarios).
I will take the workaround of not using Keys for that large Collection if I need to, but it makes my actual validation against this set of lists that bit harder later on, because I cannot just use the KeyExists method, but will have to write a slower function to crawl the un-labelled Collection looking for a match.

Comment: Don't use a collection.  The scripting dictionary is more optimised for the data structure you are using.  You then also get the .Exists method for free.

Comment: If you need something even more flexible than the scripting dictionary take a look at the cHashD dictionary  here https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?834515-Simple-and-fast-lightweight-HashList-Class-(no-APIs)

Comment: @freeflow, I would ordinarily do exactly this, BUT I need this code to be exportable into any arbitrary workbook (the reasons are hard to explain concisely, but it's an architectural decision to get user buy-in to the tool) - so I need native VBA functionality, without having to set References. Unless anyone is aware of how to enable the scripting runtime programatically, but that sounds like something Microsoft would block?

Comment: P.S. is it possible to nest Scripting.Dictionary objects in this same way? I know it is trivial to do the equivalent with dict objects in Python, but never tried anything more than a single 'layer' of Scripting.Dictionary in VBA. I guess in the simplest possible case, I could use Late Binding to just dim Objects and go from there, assuming nesting will work easily?

Comment: Yes.  Scripting.Dictionary objects can be nested.  Its best to write the code with early binding (i.e. using a reference to scripting.dictionaries)  but to then change to late binding 'CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")'.  This can be done in code using conditional compilation.